# ignore null values during dense_rank query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where each line correspond to prices of an object at a specific day.
Different lines can have prices for different days for the same object (they would have the same `object_ids` field)
I'm trying to fetch in a single query a line containing the most recent prices for each object, like so:

```
SELECT
   MAX(price1) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
ORDER BY day DESC),
MAX(price2) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
ORDER BY day DESC)

FROM historic_prices H3
GROUP BY object_ids;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work when the latest price is NULL and it just returns NULL... is there a way to ignore null values? I couldn't find anything.
thanks

edit:
basically I want to do the following:

```
table:

col 1 | col 2 | obj_id | date
----------------------------
null  | null  |   1    |  100
----------------------------
5     | null  |   1    |  90
---------------------------
3     | null  |   0    |  80
-----------------------------
7     |  4    |   1    |  70


result : 

col 1 | col 2 | obj_id |
-------------------------
5     | 4     | 1
---------------------
3     | null  | 0
```

Comment: Does using [`NULLS LAST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407) avoid the issue, or do you really need to ignore them all?

Comment: I'm not sure where I should put NULLS LAST. I tried at the end of the KEEP clause but I think it only changes the ordering of the days (if any of them are nulls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on 10g+, you can use the `IGNORE NULLS` clause of the analytic function [`FIRST_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions066.htm#SQLRF00642):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       object_ids, 
       FIRST_VALUE(price1 IGNORE NULLS)
          OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id ORDER BY DAY DESC
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) p1, 
       FIRST_VALUE(price2 IGNORE NULLS) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id ORDER BY DAY DESC
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) p2
  FROM historic_prices;
```

This works in 9iR2 (with your dataset at least):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2     SELECT NULL col1, NULL col2, 1 obj_id, 100 DAY FROM dual
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 5, NULL, 1, 90 FROM dual
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 3, NULL, 0, 80 FROM dual
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 7, 4, 1, 70 FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT obj_id,
  8         MAX(col1)
  9            KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DECODE(col1, NULL, 1, 0),
 10                                            DAY DESC) last_price1,
 11         MAX(col2)
 12            KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DECODE(col2, NULL, 1, 0),
 13                                            DAY DESC) last_price2
 14    FROM DATA
 15   GROUP BY obj_id;

    OBJ_ID LAST_PRICE1 LAST_PRICE2
---------- ----------- -----------
         0           3 
         1           5           4
```

Comment: Yes, better than where I was going! You can get down to the two rows the OP showed as the result with `select max(last_price1), max(last_price2), obj_ids from (<your query>) group by obj_ids`... not that I probably need to tell you that...

Comment: I don't have a database to test right now, but wouldn't the DISTINCT take care of that? Also I've tried to do it on a 9.2 and I haven't managed to do it with analytics only.

Comment: No, you get four rows back from the test data for some reason (testing in 11gR2); in fact looks like the original test data except the `7` never appears.

Comment: thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for.
However I'm a bit concerned about the size of the result of the 1st query (before "filtering" by the 2nd query that alex poole mentionned)

Comment: @AlexPoole: I was missing the windowing clause :)